# Show pdf files in iPhone's Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, safari

I've tried to make it work via iframe and googledocs like this

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&amp;embedded=true" style="width: 106%; margin-top: -10px; margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-10px; height: 480px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't showing anything. `Object` doesn't work too, because there isn't software to read pdf files.

I've also tried with `pdf.js` library, but can't make it work for me.

Have anyone solution of this problem?

Comment: What's the error? Tried with `https`?

Comment: `"...because there isn't software to read pdf files."` There you go and download some program.

Comment: It's showing blank page in Safari.

Comment: @Teemu, it is web page, and I want to make it work for all iPhone devices(with or without software).

Comment: Then copy the pdf to a png format, that's something all browsers can show without additional programs or plug-ins.